# Different height children in flexbox wrap container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have four boxes, the first is supposed to be 100%, and the other three are supposed to wrap around below and become shorter. I am attaching an image.

[image]

Right now the top element and the bottom elements are same height - how do I get the top element to be the same height? It's the sibling of the bottom elements.

Here is my CSS:

```
[ui-view]{
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  flex:1;
}
.videos{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex:1;
}

.videos .video{
  flex:33.3%;
}

.videos .video#elementOne{
  flex: 100% 1;
  display: flex;
}
.videos .video:not(#elementOne){
  display: flex;
  flex:33.3%;
}

.videos .video div.OT_publisher{
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1;
}

.videos .video div.OT_subscriber{
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="videos">
<div ng-repeat="stream in streamList" class="video" id="{{stream.elementId}}"></div>
</div>

    <div id="messages">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="message in messages">{{message}}</li>
        </ul>
        <input ng-model="currentMessage" id="chatInput"><button ng-click="sendMessage(currentMessage)">Submit</button>
    </div>
<div id="actions"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please post the HTML, and possibly a demo reproducing the problem (e.g., jsfiddle.net).

Comment: @Michael_B thanks - just added HTML

Comment: So you want the large image on top stretching the width of the container, and the input field, submit button and 2nd image aligned in a row underneath?

Comment: Not really. I'm trying to get the top image to take up more height. Making the siblings below rectangular too because they'd be shorter.

Comment: A demo is going to be optimal here. It's not really clear what you are trying to do. An image of the *intended result* would be helpful too.